# Redirect to Rewritten URL issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I 'm having a problem when trying to redirect to rewritten url.
I'm rewrite from :

`www.testdomain.com/index.php?rt=..&id=..`

to :

`www.testdomain.com/{rt}/{id}`

and trying to redirect from the old (1) to (2).

Here, my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?rt=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^rt=(.*)&id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.localdomain.com/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

And this is my problem: When I'm run in browser, It throw an error about redirect loop. But I don't know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?rt=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?rt=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```